# How to ensure thread safe call

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here is my scenario:

1. Pick up message off of a queue (IBM MQ)
2. Pass to async process (Archive the file and get fileId from DB) Thread #1
3. Shred the xml message and join to process #2 (So I can use fileId) Thread #2
4. Send shredded data to DB with fileId (From Thread #1 and Thread #2)
5. In Parallel with Steps #2 and #3 above I will modify the message and send to another queue Thread #3

**EDIT:** The reason I was thinking about using multiple threads is that for step #5 I want it to modify the xml and write to the queue regardless if Step #2 and #3 fail.  I was thinking for Step #2 and #3 that I could do archive and shred xml separately to try and speed up that process.

Number of Messages a day (200,000 to 500,000)

Question: If I am using the same message for all three processes above will I run into any issues? Should I copy the message  so that when I modify the message in Step #5 (Thread #3) I don't have any issues? I am still ignroant with multi-threading so I am just trying to think through the best way to handle this scenario and have the most throughput.

Using C# 4.0.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be OK if the message is (treated as) immutable.
So you definitely need a copy in step 5.

For the rest: It depends, on almost everything.

You may see some advantage from threading due to the different I/O channels.

On the other hand, if there are many messages coming in then it might work just as well or better  to do all 5 steps on 1 Thread per message.

Comment: Thanks @Henk Holterman....take a look at my EDIT.  I appreciate the feedback.  What you said makes sense.

Comment: Well, that's between 2 and 10 per second, not a whole lot. But it Depends on the processing time. The 'regardless if ... fails' can be realized with exception handling too.

Answer (score 1):

Shared state is one of the biggest (if not the biggest) problems when when writing multi-threaded applications. You can always do all the locking stuff, but it is still hard to keep everything working. 
If you can make your message immutable (in the sense that, every change creates a new object) you'll be ok, as it won't be any shared state.
You should consider, however, that sometimes immutable objects can be even more costly than aquiring locks and even trickier. But, in your place, I would give immutability a chance.